# RoaringBitmap is serialized to different string using node and java

Tags: java, node.js, bitmap

I'm using [roaring bitmaps](https://github.com/SalvatorePreviti/roaring-node) to store arrays of values.

When are using nodejs application to create and serialize the bitmap.
And java application fetches the serialized string and recreates the bitmap.

Below is the node js code -

```
 const RoaringBitmap32 = require('roaring/RoaringBitmap32');
const bitmap2 = new RoaringBitmap32([3, 4, 100]);
console.log('bitmap2.toArray():', bitmap2.toArray());
console.log('contentToString:', bitmap2.contentToString());
const serialized = bitmap2.serialize()
console.log("serialized " + serialized)
console.log('base 64 serialized:', serialized.toString('base64'))
console.log('deserialized:', RoaringBitmap32.deserialize(serialized).toArray())
```

Below is the output -

```
bitmap2.toArray(): [ 3, 4, 100 ]
contentToString: [3,4,100]
serialized d
base 64 serialized: AQMAAAADAAAABAAAAGQAAAA=
deserialized: [ 3, 4, 100 ]
```

Below is the java code -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MutableRoaringBitmap mrb = MutableRoaringBitmap.bitmapOf(3, 4, 100);
    System.out.println("starting with  bitmap "+ mrb);
    ByteBuffer outbb = ByteBuffer.allocate(mrb.serializedSizeInBytes());
    mrb.serialize(outbb);
    outbb.flip();
    String serializedstring = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(outbb.array());
    System.out.println("serializedstring :\n" + serializedstring);
}
```

The output of the java code is -

```
starting with  bitmap {3,4,100}
serializedstring :
OjAAAAEAAAAAAAIAEAAAAAMABABkAA==
```

My question is why the bitmap with same contents produces different serialized string?

How can I make serialization and deserialization of roaring bitmap interoperable between java and node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to use portable flag as mentioned in this [comment](https://github.com/RoaringBitmap/RoaringBitmap/issues/367#issuecomment-576771827) in nodejs.

below are the usages

For **Serialization** -

```
 const serialized = bitmap2.serialize(true);
```

For **Deserialization** -

```
 RoaringBitmap32.deserialize(serialized, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an endianness issue. From the Javadoc:

> Note: Java's data structures are in big endian format. Roaring serializes to a little endian format, so the bytes are flipped by the library during serialization to ensure that what is stored is in little endian---despite Java's big endianness. You can defeat this process by reflipping the bytes again in a custom DataOutput which could lead to serialized Roaring objects with an incorrect byte order.

Comment: any example how to change this endianness issue?

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to confirm that this is the issue (compare the deserialized bit strings to confirm the bits in each byte are reversed) and then figure out where this is happening.  It shouldn't be too hard.